# fbml show logged user's name

Tags: facebook, fbml, facebook-fbml

What app can I use to make a welcome tab and show the logged user's name on a Facebook page. I know FBML is not going to be around for much longer, but this is the perfect solution for me.

Thanks!

an example: http://www.facebook.com/pages/Whisper-of-%C7%9D%CA%8Co%D7%9F/187852637947344

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine using a Facebook application that serves landing pages like http://apps.facebook.com/iframehost-d/ along with the fb:name tag http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/name/ to show the logged in user's name.

But given that FBML is being deprecated, the better way is to use the Graph API with something like this:

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  alert('Your name is ' + response.name);
});
```

Comment: I tried what you said here: http://dev.cexa.ro/eforma/index.html but it is not working. Can you tell what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I looked at your source code, and the problem is that you're not using your own app id (your code still says YOUR_APP_ID). You should follow the instructions here under Getting Started and try that out: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/